# why" Element.dispatchevent()" is not working?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on extension that automatically select variant on the AliExpress but the problem is i need to dispatch click event to make variant selected but my dispatch event is not working i don't know whats going wrong there as there is no error in console.

```
setTimeout(function(){
selectAttributes();},3000);
function selectAttributes(){
    chrome.storage.local.get(null,function(result){
    for(i=0; i<result.ae_items.length; i++){
        console.log(result.ae_items[i].attributes);
        for (var key in result.ae_items[i].attributes){
            $(".sku-property-list").each(function(){
                $(".sku-property-item").each(function(){
                    if($(this).has("img")){
                        var title=$(this).children(".sku-property- 
                         image").children("img").attr("title");
                        if(title==result.ae_items[i].attributes[key]){
                            var event=new Event("click");
                            this.dispatchEvent(event);
                        }

                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Try `new Event("click", {bubbles: true});`

Comment: not worked for me

Comment: Assuming you reloaded the extension on `chrome://extensions` page and the tab too, another idea is to use `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `touchstart`, `pointerdown` and so on. You can view the events used by the site in devtools: https://puu.sh/FvhWh/2f82ac0d81.png

Comment: its using click event